# Rollup with d3 plugin : reference is not defined

Tags: javascript, d3.js, module, babeljs, rollupjs

I'm quite new using rollup to make custom d3 build. I'm trying to use the [d3-annotation plugin](https://github.com/susielu/d3-annotation) but when the build is done, I get an error in my console:`ReferenceError: d3Dispatch is not defined`
In the builded file, it seems that all the property like `d3Dispatch`, `d3Selection`, etc. aren't "translated". [The require lines](https://github.com/susielu/d3-annotation/blob/master/d3-annotation.js#L3266) disappear too (which is probably normal).

Here is rollup config file:

```
import { queue } from "d3-queue";
import { event, select, selectAll } from "d3-selection";
import { scaleLinear, scaleIdentity } from "d3-scale";
import { drag } from "d3-drag";
import { json } from "d3-request";
import { annotation, annotationCalloutCircle } from "d3-svg-annotation";

export {
    queue,
    event,
    select,
    selectAll,
    scaleLinear,
    scaleIdentity,
    drag,
    json,
    annotation,
    annotationCalloutCircle
}
```

Which it used with a gulp task:

```
gulp.task('d3-rollup', function() {
    return rollup({
        entry: 'js/custom.d3.js',
        plugins: [
            babel(),
            nodeResolve({ jsnext: true }),
            commonjs(),
            rollup_uglify()
        ]
    }).then(function(bundle) {
        return bundle.write({
            format: 'umd',
            moduleName: 'd3',
            dest: 'js/d3.min.js'
        });
    });
});
```

I just can't get what is wrong. Do I need to import another property ? Have you an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the es6/jsnext/module setup for the package.json of the project. It has been resolved in versions 1.6.0 and up.